# Python counting positive integers

Tags: python

How would I change this in order to count the number of sevens in a positive integer.

```
num = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

while num >= 1:
    digit = num % 10
    num = num//10
    print(digit)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your code as a basis, just declare a variable to count the sevens, and increment it when the current digit is a seven:

```
sevens = 0
while num >= 1:
    digit = num % 10
    if digit == 7:
        sevens += 1
    num = num // 10
print(sevens)
```

Of course, there are more pythonic ways to do this:

```
num = input('Enter a positive integer: ')
print(num.count('7'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a string, then use the count function.

```
num = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
print(str(num).count('7'))
```